# Eek! Why did the Stack Overflow icon (favicon) change?

Tags: discussion, favicon

I recently noticed that the favicon of Stack Overflow has changed. I think the lines in the logo are a little bit less thick in the new version (this is the major difference I've noticed). The same has happened to the meta site favicon:

new 16x16: [image: new 16px]

new 32x32: [image: new 32px]

old 16x16: [image: Old 16px]

old 32x32: [image: Old 32px]

What is the reason for this?

Comment: I guess the design was refined. It happens. The Meta icon was updated too.

Comment: Hehe I just noticed it as well :)

Comment: The new ones just look wirey instead of nice like the originals.

Comment: I just upgraded the Surface to IE 11, so I thought it was an artifact of that.

Comment: It looks so weak compared to all the other favicons.

Comment: @SuperScript my thought was "wispy".

Comment: @Whomever downvoted: care to explain?

Comment: On my 2560x1440 screen the icon is neigh invisible. Even when wearing glasses. Please change back. It looks like it has been greyed out http://twitpic.com/e0jmsj

Comment: i don't like change, please.

Comment: Oh CRAP people, everyone panic for this signals the end of the world as we know it!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

After 4 years, I finally updated the favicon to resemble a full Stack Overflow logo because we have the technology now.

Comment: What technology are you talking about? Beacon-generator machines of some sort? :)

Comment: @AdamArold Oculus Rift

Comment: @Jin how come Oculus Rift made it possible?

Comment: @AdamArold Doubtless he was joking. The staff have weird humour.

Comment: I'm a bit tired right now so I did not understand the joke. I thought it was some weird humour though.

Comment: @Jin it just became thinner, unless I miss anything?

Comment: This may be an edge case, but for me they're significantly harder to distinguish: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9mYS6.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard it became thinner to make room for the 2 bars that were missing from the old favicon(16x16).

Comment: Oh dear god, they replaced one tiny image with a slightly different tiny image!  What are we going to do?!  PANIC!  REVOLT!  CHAOS!

Comment: OculusRift - the tool of Facebook? Boo and Hiss!

Comment: Oh my, I focused only on the 32x32 icon for some reason. Good work then @Jin, although I fear many will want the old icon back. Prepare your armor! :)

Comment: @jadarnel27 you know, wars started on smaller things than that! :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard smaller than 16x16?!

Comment: @m0sa never heard of the Great Wars of 3x3?!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh, that's nothing. I was once involved in a border skirmish over a 1x1 that was trying to do something nasty.

Comment: @michael don't tell me it tried to... blink!

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's *exactly* what it was trying to do. We had to call in heavy imageblockers, and the place is irradiated to this day.

Comment: Is this going to get applied to chat too? Because it's far more glaring when your top bar looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G3F6e.png). I think that may be the main opposition from @michael, and the status quo police.

Comment: @Jin needz moar black

Comment: I don't like it. : ( It's like I'm squinting or have brightness turned up or something.

Comment: New favicon looks terrible.  Very hard to see.  Looks weak and anemic on my links bar.  Most disappointing.

Comment: @jin, I'm a fan!  I have lousy (old) eyes, so it did look light at first, but now that I'm not noticing the diff from the old one, I like it better.  Nice work!

Comment: On my 2560x1440 screen the icon is neigh invisible. Even when wearing glasses. Please change back. [It looks like it has been greyed out](http://twitpic.com/e0jmsj)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Worse than that! It will create cracks and holes in the space-time fabric! It's already beginning ... I'm sure I've seen Jon Skeet's rep decreasing ... only a glitch in its least significant digit ... they are coming ... black ponies and unicorns ... WE ARE DOOMED!!!

Answer (score 12):

If anyone's interested, I made a userscript to get rid of this anemic abomination.

[**Stack Apps**](https://stackapps.com/q/4623/21692)
[**GitHub Gist**](https://gist.github.com/michaelb958/10020360)