# Questions that have more upvotes than views

Tags: bug, mso-mse-split, migration

Maybe I misunderstood something, but there are some questions that have more upvotes than views.

**Examples**:

- [Eek! Why did the Stack Overflow icon (favicon) change?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250997/eek-why-did-the-stack-overflow-icon-favicon-change)
- [February 2014 Stack Overflow Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250068/february-2014-stack-overflow-community-moderator-election-results)
- [Stack Overflow is not yet a vast wasteland: a history of moderator tooling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling)

How can it be? Is it a bug?

Comment: Looks like the view-counts didn't get migrated with the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*This is a bug.* These questions are migrated from **meta.stackexchange.com**.

[image]

And during migration the upvotes got migrated but views are not migrated.

For these questions -

> Total number of votes = Number of votes in meta.stackexchange.com + Number of votes in meta.stack.overflow.
>   Total number of views = Number of views in meta.stack.overflow.

*That's why these questions have more upvotes, than views.*

Comment: Yeah that's a bug.

Comment: @djechlin I edited my question.

Comment: Yep, I'd say that's more accurate.

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari, What about the reputation of the old votes?

Comment: @Pacerier As per me, questions should be migrated with both votes and views. Not the votes alone.

Comment: Is this the same thing that is going on with non-meta posts like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript